# Grpc interceptor is not being called

Tags: c#, grpc

I have added MyInterceptor which is being inherited by Grpc.Core.Interceptors.Interceptor:

```
public class MyInterceptor : Interceptor
{
    public override Task<TResponse> UnaryServerHandler<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request, ServerCallContext context, UnaryServerMethod<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
    {
        //do something
        return base.UnaryServerHandler(request, context, continuation);
    }
}
```

And I am enabling this interceptor in following way:

```
_server = new Server(channelOptions)
{
   Services = { Service.ServerServiceDefinition() },
   Ports = { new ServerPort(...) },
};

var interceptor = new MyInterceptor();

foreach(var service in _server.Services)
{
   service.Intercept(interceptor);
}
```

And each time, I called grpc method, the interceptor is not being called.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Intercept` method *returns* the decorated `ServerServiceDefinition`; as such, you probably want something more like:

```cs
var interceptor = new MyInterceptor();
_server = new Server(channelOptions)
{
   Services = { Service.ServerServiceDefinition().Intercept(interceptor) },
   Ports = { new ServerPort(...) },
};
```